# Oracle SQL Developer vs SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I just installed Oracle SQL Developer, and attached it to my SQL Server. I like to expose myself to different environments. I was wondering if anyone knows of any benefits that the Oracle SQL IDE has over the SQL Server IDE. Is there any reason at all why I should keep the Oracle IDE, if the only sever I play with at the moment is SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: The question looks like a well-defined and valid programming question to me. I wish I had experience with the Oracle SQL Developer application and could help you.

Comment: I use SQL Developer and SQL Navigator (both on Oracle) and my use of SQL Server was a long time ago. I find SQL Developer quite frustrating at times though when compared to SQL Navigator. If I was you and you are only using SQL Server, get an IDE that is specific to that as it will have better intgration with the database and its nuances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot think of any advantages or reasons to use Oracle SQL Developer if you only do SQL Server development.

At best, you are limiting yourself on the SQL Server features that you cannot access via SQL Developer. Things like backing up your db, attaching, detaching, scripting, user security, etc. Not to mention SQL Server's T-SQL awareness that Oracle will not have.

Being able to attach Oracle SQL Developer to SQL Server is really meant for people integrating the two. Otherwise, use a SQL Server specific tool.

PS: Consider, a lot of Oracle DBAs and Developers don't use Oracle SQL Developer anyway. If you want to expose yourself to a good tool, try Toad, SQL Navigator or DBArtisan (for Oracle).

Comment: OFF-TOPIC: SQL Developer has gotten A LOT better the past couple years. It is free. Compare that price to TOAD. TOAD also seems to get even more buggy with every release.

Comment: @RobertGreathouse - No doubt. SQL Developer has improved since 2011 when I posted this answer. I use it frequently, so I'm familiar with it. But I also use Toad, RedGate, Embarcadero, and Devart as a professional Oracle consultant and I still have problems with the current version of SQL Developer. Parts of it are broken. It is a long way from comparing to Toad. But again, its free so it blows Toad out of the water in that department.

Comment: @RobertGreathouse - An anecdote: In May (2014) I tried to use SQL Developer's data migration assistant to port a customer's database from MySQL to Oracle. Something I've done before with other tools. The resulting script was so chock full of bugs, I gave up and went back to my own tools. If you haven't used the migration assistant, and aren't familiar with its model, its worth trying to get a feeling for it. Its neat, but it breaks too often. But I'm not complaining: I'm happy for them to leave the tools space for us little guys. If SQL Dev gets too good it will make boutique shops obsolete.